# How to manage web application configuration during run-time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I need to be able to change some configuration variables at run-time. I don't want to store these values in database and I don't want the app to restart each time `web.config` gets updated.

**Idea:**

Store default values in `web.config` which are loaded at application start into `HttpContext` and than use [stateful action filters](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/aspnet-mvc-filters-and-statefulness.html) to determine application behaviour depending on those values.

- What are your thoughts on this approach?
- What are good and bad sides?
- Can this be done differently?

Comment: I'm not sure you can prevent the app from restarting if you update the web.config.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's why I thought to use HttpContext as a storage for current values, and web.config only for defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [custom configuration file](http://blog.yapb.net/post/2009/09/22/Creating-your-own-Custom-Configuration-Section.aspx) to create your own XML file to store these settings in.

Comment: I've read the blogpost, but I'm not sure what you're suggesting. Are you suggesting to use external configuration file or just a simple xml independent of web.config? As I remember former will be cached and latter won't, or I got this wrong?

Comment: Create your own custom XML file. You should be able to write to and read from this file at Runtime.